# 2013 Chevy Malibu serious electric issues

Tags: chevrolet

My 2013 Malibu has very serious electrical problems.  Radio cuts out. All interior light flicker or go out. Steering locks up. Sometimes there is a no start as if the battery was completely drained. But if you wait a while it starts up. Key gets stuck in ignition as well. I really need help with this please.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What have you done to try and decipher what's going on? If you haven't, the first place to start looking is with the grounds (battery to body; engine to body; whatever else you can find).

Comment: I was thinking that. The Negative cable to the battery is loose where the cable connects to the clamp.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the ignition lock cylinder and switch. All of the problems you describe point to that as the problem. Especially the key getting stuck and the intermittent no starts.

Comment: Not really. None of the problems he listed sounds much like a failing ignition switch and definitely not the lock cylinder itself. It is normal operation that the ignitions on GM's do not allow key release when the battery is low/dead.  I would say more likely to be a bad connection with battery, a failing battery or a short somewhere that is bringing the voltage down.